# Move along an arc in p5js

Tags: javascript, graphics, geometry, processing, p5.js

I am having so much trouble fixing this part of my code.  I am creating an interactive picture in P5js. Part of the picture is a sun. I want the sun to move across the screen in an arc as the mouse moves back and forth across the screen. Like this:

[image: diagram]

My thought is essentially to map mouse to a certain range of angles and then use that angle to calculate the position of my sun, but I'm having a lot of trouble wrapping my head around circular motion.

Specifically, I can get something to move circularly, but I don't really understand how to change the center point of said circle.  Here is the code for my sun object and also a link to the Sketch on openprocessing where you can see it in action and play around with the code:

```
function Sun(x,y,w,h,c1,c2){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.c1 = c1;
    this.c2 = c2;

    this.center = createVector(width/2,height/2);
    this.pos = createVector(this.x,this.y);
    var dx = this.center.x - this.pos.x;
    var dy = this.center.y - this.pos.y;
    var initAngle = atan2(dx,dy);
    this.angle =  initAngle;
    this.constant = height/2;
    this.radius = dist(this.center.x,this.center.y,this.pos.x,this.pos.y);

    this.display = function(){
        noStroke();
        fill(red(c1),green(c1),blue(c1));

        //draw center point
        ellipse(this.center.x,this.center.y,10,10);

        var x = this.constant + sin(this.angle) * this.radius;
        var y = this.constant + cos(this.angle) * this.radius;
        ellipse(x,y,50,50);

        this.angle = map(mouseX,0, width, initAngle, initAngle + PI);
    }
}
```

https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/591063

Thanks in advance for any help, I am just having trouble connecting my old high school geometry into code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to look into [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system).

Basically, you have the following:

- A center point that you want your sun to rotate around.
- An angle you want your sun to be rotate.
- A distance between the center point and the sun.

And you can calculate the position of the sun using the `cos()` and `sin()` functions:

```
var sunX = centerX + cos(angle) * distance;
var sunY = centerY + sin(angle) * distance;
```

Then, the only question becomes how to map the `mouseX` position to the angle. For this, you can use the `map()` function. The `map()` function takes an angle between two values (like `mouseX` being between `0` and `width`) and maps it to another range (like `0` and `2*PI` for your angle). Something like this:

```
var angle = map(mouseX, 0, width, 0, 2*PI);
```

You'll probably want to play with the values a bit. Using `0` and `2*PI` will give you a full circle. If you only want a half circle, you'll want to use something like `PI` and `2*PI`.

More info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/).

Comment: ahhhh, thank you! I did not understand that the constant value I'm adding to my x and y were the center point. that makes so much sense! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

line 28 and 29 in Sun

```
    var x = this.constant + sin(this.angle + HALF_PI) * this.radius;
    var y = this.constant + cos(this.angle +HALF_PI) * this.radius;
```

change your draw to this

```
function draw() {
    if(frameCount % 200 == 0) clouds.push(new Cloud());
    sky.display();
    sun.display(); // brought this line from bottom to behind mountains
    mountain.display();
    for(var i = 0; i < clouds.length; i++){
        clouds[i].display();
        if(!clouds[i].inBounds()){
            clouds.splice(i,1);
        }
    }

}
```